# VBA Runtime Error 1004 “Application-defined or Object-defined error” when using Index Range function

Tags: vba, excel

In my macro, I have the following code :

```
Set v = Application.WorksheetFunction.Index(Worksheets("Sheet2").Range(Cells(2, 1), Cells(33, 3)), Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(1, (Worksheets("Sheet2").Range(Cells(2, 1), Cells(33, 1)) = Osheet.Cells(i, 2).Value) * (Worksheets("Sheet2").Range(Cells(2, 2), Cells(33, 2)) = Left(Osheet.Cells(5, 6).Value, 1)), 0), 3)
```

Data is initially in Sheet 1 (this is Osheet as used in code) from where 2 parameters are being selected & Index Match function is being used to get the data from Sheet 2.

While running the macro, Runtime Error 1004, Application Defined or Object defined error is being displayed.

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Without data example, I cannot reproduce your problem.  But, in addition to properly qualifying the range references, as noted by @Vityata, it is not clear to me that your formula is returning an object, yet you are using `Set`.  Also, you have a few Boolean comparisons in your formula.  What are they doing?

Comment: @RonRosenfeld Sheet 2 contains the data below Farbe Size SKU Code
weiß S 5671
weiß M 5672
weiß L 5673
weiß XL 5674
Sheet 1 contains Order quantity for selected products. So objective of this code is to find the respective SKU code(from Sheet2) where there is a corresponding order record in Sheet 1. This SKU code is being passed to Set v = & then further v is being sent to another sheet for other process. Hope i am making sense here. Please help if you have understood my problem.

Comment: As I wrote, I wouldn't even try to reproduce your problem without data that can be downloaded into Excel.  But the `Set` keyword is used for objects. SKU codes are usually string variables, and I'm not sure what your formula is returning, but parts of it are generating Booleans.

Comment: Try to explain how to possibly reproduce the problem otherwise it seems it is a matter of debugging your code..

Comment: Apart from the unqualified `Cells`, it looks like the problem will be because of the array operations (such as `Range(Cells(2, 1), Cells(33, 1)) = Osheet.Cells(i, 2).Value`) which I don't think VBA can handle.

Answer (score 1):

A quick guess:

```
with Worksheets("Sheet2")
    Set v = Application.WorksheetFunction.Index(.Range(.Cells(2, 1), .Cells(33, 3)), Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(1, (.Range(.Cells(2, 1), .Cells(33, 1)) = Osheet.Cells(i, 2).Value) * (.Range(.Cells(2, 2), .Cells(33, 2)) = Left(Osheet.Cells(5, 6).Value, 1)), 0), 3)
end with
```

The trick is that you should give a reference of the spreadsheet to the cell/range as well. Just a VBA thing! :)

See Msdn for more info https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff196273.aspx

Comment: Thanks for prompt help, I tried the same in my code & reran the macro.....however the same error is being displayed

Comment: @AjayBansal - Vityata had missed a couple of incorrect references toward the end of the line.  I have just edited the answer so try copying it again now.  (Our assumption is that the basic formula is correct, and it is just the unqualified `Cells` references that was causing the issue.)

Comment: @YowE3K, Thanks for editing the code.Unfortunately, the same error 1004 is displayed

Comment: @AjayBansal OK, in that case we will need to look more closely at what you are trying to do in your formula.  (BTW - Have you tried doing the equivalent of your formula within Excel itself, just to make sure it is logical?)  It may be helpful if you update the question to say what your formula is trying to do.

Comment: @YowE3K. I have tried formula in Excel. In the excel, after writing the formula, it is mandatory to use CTRL+ SHIFT+ ENTER Key & the curly braces { } are displayed automatically in the formula. Without using this, Excel formula doesnt work. I am not able to find if there is any corresponding step i need to perform here. Basically, I am trying to find SKU code from Sheet 2 based on Item Order rcvd in Sheet 1. If an Itemorder found, then use item details (2 variables in code) to find SKU code frm Sheet 2 & pass it to v. Then v is sent to another sheet for further processing. Hope this clears.

Comment: Vitaya (and @AjayBansal ) You shouldn't thank me so soon - there was a missing bracket too which I didn't notice.  But it won't help anyway because, although your answer solves one problem, it won't help with the next one which is that the formula is trying to get VBA to do array operations that it can't do.  (Such as `.Range(.Cells(2, 1), .Cells(33, 1)) = Osheet.Cells(i, 2).Value`)  And I don't use those sort of operations enough to know whether there is an easy way (e.g. a `WorksheetFunction` function) to do that.